# Is "horsies" a valid word?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I saw some people say or spell "horsies" instead of "horses". Since I didn't find the word in dictionary, I wonder if *horsies* is a valid variation of *horses* or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the word from a more inclusive dictionary:
[Wiktionary "horsy"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/horsy#English)

> horsy (plural horsies) (childish or endearing) A child's term or name for a horse.

So, it's a valid word if you are less than six years old, or are talking to someone who is.

Horsie (or horsy) also appears as an adjective in other dictionaries.